# How to inspect the completion popup in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to inspect the completion popup (intellisense) in VSCode using the builtin developer tool (<kbd>ctrl+shift+i</kbd>). However, when I press this shortcut, the popup disappeared. What's the proper way to inspect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute in Console in Dev Tools:

```js
setTimeout(() => { debugger; }, 5000);
```

- Trigger completion in editor
- Wait until debugging starts